# How do I upload an image to the file system in react using multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, multer

I am trying to send a file to folder using multer.

Currently I can post the file successfully, receiving the correct response, however the file does not save in the folder called uploads.

This is my UI code.

```
<form action="/requests/upload" method="POST" encType="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="profileImage" type="file" />
    <button className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Below is my endpoint in a file called routes.js.

```
const upload = multer({ dest: '../../public/uploads' })

router.post('/upload', upload.single('profileImage'), (req, res) => {
    return res.json({ status: 'Image Uploaded' })
})
```

The file structure is like so:

[image]

Note: /requests/* are set with
`app.use('/requests', routesUrls)`

Thank you for anyone who helps.

Comment: Does your code throw an error? Is it simply not saving?

Comment: @sandrooco There are no errors, it just doesn't seem to save

Comment: I assume that your routes.js is in the routes folder? Then it will save it in a public folder inside src and not my-app.
My guess: `const upload = multer({ dest: '../../../public/uploads' })`

Comment: yh the routes.js file is in the routes folder. Also for some reason even if i move uploads to the routes directory, it still doesn't save as `dest: './uploads'`

`res.file` does return something but still the file doesn't upload to uploads.
@sandrooco

Comment: Another thing to add is that once the POST is successful, in the request the path of where the file is stored is in.
public/uploads/5aee1b1c1890ae7215fb307deeca7a91
instead of my-app/public/uploads